# Python get the list of process with publisher name

Tags: python, windows, cmd, wmi, psutil

I am building a python application to list all the running process (like the windows taskbar).

[image: Windows Tasklist]

I need to group the process based on the publisher of the apps. I have tried using the python library `WMI` and `psutil`. Using both the libraries, I am not able to get the publisher name.

Is there any way to get the publisher name in windows?

Comment: You won't get that information from process. Get the filename and query it's digital signature and extract "Subject Name" to get the publisher info

Comment: I googled and can't find anything to fetch signature in Python. Can you give me reference?

Comment: Not sure about python.. but you can try your luck with `win32api` to see if any api is available.  The equivalent  function in `winapi` is `CertGetNameString`